# Can only click jQuery element once before it stops working

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following code:

```
$("#another").click(function() {
    $('#another').replaceWith('<a id="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini disabled"><i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Loading...</a>');
    $.get('another.php', { 'cycle' : i }, function(data) {
        $('tbody').append(data);
        $("#another").replaceWith('<a id="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Load another cycle</a>');
    });
    i++;
});
```

When I click the element with the id of another, it loads once. After one click, it won't work again.

Comment: Overwriting the element with `replaceWith` destroys the event handler, so you have to rebind it each time

Comment: How would I go about either rebinding it or how could I avoid this problem?

Comment: How many times do you need it to work? Better worded: How many cycles do you need? Also, where does the variable `i` come from?

Comment: @SimpleCoder Infinite, as many times as the user wants. `i` is defined right above it. `var i = 1; $("#another").click(function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the element with another, all listeners will be removed. To avoid this you either add the listener again to the new element

```
$('#another').bind('click', function() {
  //do something
});
```

or move the code to a function and add a `onclick` attribute to your element.

```
onclick="my_function();"
```

in your current javascript it would be

```
$('#another').replaceWith('<a id="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini disabled" onclick="my_function();"><i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Loading...</a>');
```

Comment: This is so obviously simple that I feel really stupid right now... The function approach works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the node with a node that doesn't have the event listener.

Basically before the click  you have

```
[#another]
    ^
    |
[clickListener]
```

You then build another button (`<a id="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini disabled"><i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Loading...</a>`)

```
[#another]     [#another](2)
    ^
    |
[clickListener]
```

then we replace the first another with a second one in the layout:

```
[#another]               [#another](2)
    ^
    |
[clickListener]
```

*oh wait*, nothing changed in my model. That's because the click listener was linked to that first object ( that is no longer visible), whereas the visible one is still there.

---

So codewise, what does this mean? It simply means you'll need to attach the event listener back on there. Here's how I'd have done it

```
var onClick=function(){
    $('#another').replaceWith('<a id="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini disabled"><i class="icon-refresh icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Loading...</a>')
    .click(onClick); // <--- this is the important line!

    $.get('another.php', { 'cycle' : i }, function(data) {
        $('tbody').append(data);
        $("#another").replaceWith('<a id="another" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Load another cycle</a>');
    });
    i++;
}

$("#another").click(onClick);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. While I'm not using your code (it's easier using the function approach), it's quite informative.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to just keep the same button, with the same event handler. Just dynamically change the text and increment `i`. Try this:

```
// Execute in a closure to isolate all the local variables
// Optional, but I like doing this when counter variables are involved
(function() {
    var button = $("#another");
    var a = button.find("a");
    var i = 1;

    button.click(function() {
        // Replace the inner html, not the entire element
        a.html("<i class='icon-refresh icon-white'</i>&nbsp;Loading...");
        $.get("another.php", {
            cycle: i
        }, function(data) {
            $("tbody").append(data);
            a.html("<i class='icon-plus icon-white'></i>&nbsp;Load another cycle");            
            i++;
        });
    });
})();
```

The benefit of this method is that there is less DOM manipulation, no inline JavaScript, and **no global functions or variables**. There really is no reason to destroy the button each time and recreate it if the outer markup is the same.

Comment: This is also a very good idea. I didn't remember the function to do this, nor did I know a good way of describing it, so I just did it my way.

Comment: @Syfaro: I am not trying to sway you to give me the rep, but I highly recommend you do it my way. You don't want to mess with inline JavaScript and global functions.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It still loads the next result, but it doesn't change the button to the loading one. The code is live at [this page](http://gregcordover.net/live/DutyRoster/names.php) (well, not that page, but you have to go through that page to get where the live code is, you can go straight [to it](http://gregcordover.net/live/DutyRoster/result.php) but none of the data is there)

Comment: I'm using the function version on the live page now... I'll look more into doing it your way, though.